# How to do to-do calendars for php site - any good AJAX or php libraries for that?

Tags: php, jquery, calendar, todo

If you show the to-do as a calendar - on a php site, possibility to edit daily tasks, etc.

[image: 1]

Is it made with AJAX or some PHP/CSS library/application?

Are there any good php plugins for to-do calendars?

Answer (score 1):

It can be done using different tecnologies like Java, PHP, Ruby, and so on. However, if you choose php you should use php + mysql and css. The Ajax interactions are not indispensable but I think that a good web 2.0 application should use AJAX (jQuery library, for example).

Try to see here: http://sourceforge.net/search/?q=php+calendar